# Texto tabulado no se muestra ordenado en la pre-visualización

Tags: c#, windows-forms

**Transfondo**

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de tipo Windows Forms "Framework 4.0" el cual permite la pre-visualización *(antes de la impresión)* de ciertos datos.

Los datos en cuestión se dividen así:

- Texto informativo - separado en 3 líneas
- Saltos de líneas
- Datos de un `DataGridView`.

Este es un ejemplo de la información que deseo imprimir *(usando la clase `PrintDocument`)*:

```
MI RESTAURANTE S.A.S.
CALLE 123 # 11-12
85544792
BOGOTA, CUNDINAMARCA 123
*** REPORTE DE LOS MODIFICADORES ***

de 19/01/2018 a 19/02/2018

Modificador Cantidad    Valor   
Pollo Agridulce 6   0,00
Cerdo Agridulce 28  0,00
No 1    3   0,00
No 2    3   0,00
No 3    7   0,00
No 4    8   0,00
3/4 2   0,00
Bien    1   0,00
Sin     14  0,00
Camaron 13  0,00
Sin Raices  5   0,00
Sin Cebollin    3   0,00
Cebolla 2   0,00
Aceite Oliva    5   0,00
Con 5   0,00
```

Estoy usando `PrintPreviewDialog` para la pre-visualización de los datos a imprimir.

**Problema**

Al pre-visualizar la información, ésta "a pesar de estar tabulada correctamente" no se muestra organizada.

He intentado:

- Usar `SelectAll()` y `Clipboard.SetText` para obtener toda la información del `DataGridView` - como se muestra en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10525686/4092887).
- Recorrer el `DataGridView` para intentar armar una tabla *(usando caracteres como "=" ó "|" como delimitadores)* para establecer un tamaño fijo de los datos.
- Determinar la cantidad de caracteres de cada celda para determinar si agrego o no espacios *(emulando la tabulación)*, pero el código de pre-visualización se aplica para mas de un reporte y éstos pueden poseer muchísimas líneas y diferente cantidad de columnas.

Este es un ejemplo de cómo realizo actualmente la tabulación de los datos obtenidos del `DataGridView`:

```
// Filas que tendrá el archivo. - "tbl" es el DataSource del DataGridView:
sstring vlrTableCell = "";
for (int row = 0; row < tbl.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    // Asignar el valor del arreglo de items a la variable local.
    vlrTableCell = string.Join("\t", tbl.Rows[row].ItemArray);
    // ...
}
```

Todos los intentos resultan en que los valores no se muestran correctamente tabulados u organizados *(en la pre-visualización)*.

Lo que me gustaría obtener es una estructura similar a esto *(en la pre-visualización)*:

```
MI RESTAURANTE S.A.S.
CALLE 123 # 11-12
85544792
BOGOTA, CUNDINAMARCA 123
*** REPORTE DE LOS MODIFICADORES ***

de 19/01/2018 a 19/02/2018

Modificador         Cantidad    Valor   
Pollo Agridulce     6           0,00
Cerdo Agridulce     28          0,00
No 1                3           0,00
No 2                3           0,00
No 3                7           0,00
No 4                8           0,00
3/4                 2           0,00
Bien                1           0,00
Sin                 14          0,00
Camaron             13          0,00
Sin Raices          5           0,00
Sin Cebollin        3           0,00
Cebolla             2           0,00
Aceite Oliva        5           0,00
Con                 5           0,00
```

Una alternativa sería usar ReportViewer, pero no sabría cómo usar este control para lograr un resultado similar.

¿Qué puedo usar o cómo puedo obtener los valores del `DataGridView` y que éstos estén correctamente tabulados *(es decir, que se muestren correctamente tabulados en la pre-visualización de la información)*?

Comment: Nos vendría bien ver como generas esos espacios. Usas `/t`? Por otro lado, si, es mejor reportviewer, mucho mas potente y flexible (aunque su manejo tiene ciertos problemas en ocasiones)

Comment: @Pikoh he actualizado la pregunta. Sé que es pedir mucho, pero si conoces de un tutorial que pueda seguir para intentar esto, te estaré agradecido.

Comment: Puedes empezar por [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/reporting-services/reporting-services-tutorials-ssrs)

Comment: Lo que esta haciendo el tab es correcto, lo que pasa es que en algunas lineas necesitas mas de un tab.

Comment: Comprendo, pero, la cuestión es ¿cómo puedo determinar la cantidad de tabs para que la información se muestre bien tabulada en la pre-visualización?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución válida para este caso fue usar el método [PadRight](https://www.dotnetperls.com/padright).

> Devuelve un nuevo `string` que alinea a la izquierda los caracteres de
>   esta cadena al rellenarlos con espacios a la derecha, para una
>   longitud total especificada.

Modifiqué mi código para generar un archivo .txt con la información almacenada en una variable de tipo `DataTable`:

```
// Generar archivo de texto con la información del DataTable "tbl_datos_a_exportar".
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string resultado = "";
    int cant_espacios = 12; // Cantidad de espacios que tendrán las columnas por defecto.

    try
    {   
        // Armar las columnas.
        for (int col = 0; col < tbl_datos_a_exportar.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            resultado += tbl_datos_a_exportar.Columns[col].ColumnName.PadRight(cant_espacios, ' ');
        }

        // Espacio para generar las filas.
        resultado += "\r\n";

        // Armar las filas.
        for (int fila = 0; fila < tbl_datos_a_exportar.Rows.Count; fila++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < tbl_datos_a_exportar.Columns.Count; col++)
            {
                resultado += tbl_datos_a_exportar.Rows[fila][col].ToString().PadRight(cant_espacios, ' ');
            }
            resultado += "\r\n";
        }

        // Crear el archivo en la misma ubicación en donde se encuentra el .exe
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@".\prueba.txt", resultado);
        MessageBox.Show("Archivo generado correctamente.", "Programa", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hubo un error: " + ex.Message, "Programa", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Al establecer la cantidad de espacios para cada columna "en este caso, dejé establecido 15 espacios", pude obtener un resultado similar al resultado esperado en la pregunta.

Si la información varía de longitud, se debe establecer un fijo diferente para cada situación; pero, PadRight y PadLeft son muy útiles para este propósito.